# I am trying to find a way to get the total transaction number for a list of Ethereum addresses

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum

I am working on some tools that will allow me to finish my blockchain analysis project and I need help.

I have a list of 1000 ***Ethereum addresses*** and I am trying to get the ***total transaction number*** for *each* of these addresses.

*Solutions I've come up with so far:*

- I looked into the web3.py library and read their documentation but I couldn't seem to find a function like `web3.eth.get_transaction_count({address})` it seemed promising at first but now I don't see any use for it.
- I looked into blockchain.info's API, they do in fact have an endpoint that returns the total transactions number, but they only do bitcoin + they have a rate limit, bummer..
- I looked into etherscan.io's API, same as web3.py, they don't return total transaction information...

Is there any possible way one could fetch the total transactions number for an Ethereum address? Without having to worry about rate limits etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is to use the `blockscout` API.
Here is the documentation: [Blockscout API](https://blockscout.com/eth/mainnet/api-docs)

Use the `txlist` API from `account` module:

`?module=account&action=eth_get_balance&address={addressHash}`